# More efficient way of filtering users on past behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets: one recommendation output and other one activity data set which gives information regarding what activity or what content a user has browsed in past 2 months.

Sample recommendation data

```
id  content
  1   100
  1   101
  2   102
  2   103
  3   103
  4   105
```

Sample useractivity data

```
id  content
1              34
5              23
2              102
2              103
3              103
6              100
```

My objective is to remove those content from recommendation dataset for a user , which he has seen in past 2 months as depicted in the activity dataset. Now I take the common ids between these two datasets and for common ids I extract subsets of the two data for each id and add the end, add the uncommon ids to the output.

Present solution works, but its horribly inefficient in terms of large datasets. Actual datasets have 30,000+ user ids. If someone can help in some other method in term of list comprehension or any other method, it would be appreciated

```
common_muids = list(set(useractivity_ids).intersection(reco_ids))


final_rec1 = reco[reco.masteruserid.isin(common_muids)]
final_rec2 = reco[~(reco.masteruserid.isin(common_muids))]

d=DataFrame()

for i in common_muids:
    final_rec_reduced=final_rec1[final_rec1.id==i]
    useractivity_reduced=useractivity[useractivity.id==i]
    useractivity_reduced_tbids=useractivity_reduced.tbid.unique().tolist()
    final_rec_reduced=final_rec_reduced[~(       final_rec_reduced.tbid.isin(useractivity_reduced_tbids))]
    d=d.append(final_rec_reduced)
```

At the end:

```
d=d.append(final_rec2)
```

Final output is:

```
id  tbid
1   100
1   101
4   105
```

Comment: Sounds like something you'd want to try to achieve in your database engine, not your python code.

Comment: No I want to achieve in python code only!! Data is as such,we have to accomplish this in the code only.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dummy variable to your `useractivity_ids` then use the pandas `merge` to compare and filter.

```
In [35]: useractivity_ids['tracker'] = 1

In [39]: reco_ids = reco_ids.merge(useractivity_ids, how='left')

In [40]: reco_ids[reco_ids['tracker'].isnull()].drop('tracker', axis=1)
Out[40]: 
   id  content
0   1      100
1   1      101
5   4      105
```

In the next version of pandas (0.17), `merge` has an `indicator` keyword that lets you do this without the dummy variable.

```
In [47]: (pd.merge(reco_ids, useractivity_ids, how='left', indicator=True)
            .query('_merge == "left_only"'))
Out[47]: 
   id  content     _merge
0   1      100  left_only
1   1      101  left_only
5   4      105  left_only
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you've 2 data frames

```
recommendation_df = pd.DataFrame({'content': {0: 100, 1: 101, 2: 102, 3: 103, 4: 103, 5: 105},
 'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4}})
```

and

```
past_data = pd.DataFrame({'content': {0: 34, 1: 23, 2: 102, 3: 103, 4: 103, 5: 100},
 'id': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 6},
 'random': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}})
```

you can do left join between the two data frames

```
df = pd.merge(recommendation_df , past_data_df , how = 'left')
```

then get only rows with `null` values , these are the values that exist in recommendation data frame and doesn't exist in user activity dat frame

```
df.loc[df.random.isnull()]
```